# Are Antifa movements also anti-government?

Tags: politics

[A recent BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-40930831) claimed:

> Antifa is anti-government and anti-capitalist, and their methodologies are often perceived as more closely aligned with anarchists than the mainstream left.

Are Antifa movements anti-government generally or only in the US (or somewhere else specifically)?

Comment: Are you referring to *existing* AntiFa movements, i.e. the actual "implemenations" of the mindset, or are you asking about whether the *idea* of AntiFa includes being anti-government? (AntiFa being, by nature, left-leaning to left-extremist, makes anti-government leanings very likely, but I think that is coincidental and not "built in" to being anti-fascist. As usual, moderate influences are not as vocal as extremes...

Comment: In order to make this an examination of a notable claim, could you please quote the claim here made by a notable source? Some person on the internet isn't a notable source, but I think I can see where the BBC was making this claim. I've made an edit that refocuses this post on the BBC, and not the politics rando.

Comment: I'm surprised the mods allowed this question. It seems to come down to who labels who as what.

Comment: Just saw it. Closed as non factual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Antifa: The Antifascist Handbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=OKEwDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22antifa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkj63P797XAhVGKCYKHT8lBkAQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=anarchist&f=false):

> Some antifa groups are more Marxist while others are more anarchist or antiauthoritarian. In the United States, most have been anarchist or antiauthoritarian since the emergence of modern antifa under the name Anti-Racist Action (ARA) in the late eighties.

The 2012 book [ANTIFA](https://books.google.com/books?id=_C7rAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&dq=the%20might%20call%20me%20anarchist%20when%20I%20say%20%20scratch&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHzfea_N7XAhWCdSYKHZ3VDjsQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=the%20might%20call%20me%20anarchist%20when%20I%20say%20%20scratch&f=false) has a chapter titled:

> A little bit of anarchy is good for the soul

and also says:

> They might call me “ANARCHIST” when I say maybe it's time to burn it down and start from scratch again

[Anti-Facism in Britain](https://books.google.com/books?id=gxgxDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT344&dq=antifa%20anarchist&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI7JL4_N7XAhWBLSYKHWRhB0EQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=antifa%20anarchist&f=false) says:

> Supporters of 'Antifa' were from the anarchist tradition: Class War Federation, Anarchist Federation, Solidarity Federation, and No Platform.

[Militant Anti-Fascism: A Hundred Years of Resistance](https://books.google.com/books?id=qF1kCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT217&dq=antifa%20anarchist&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI7JL4_N7XAhWBLSYKHWRhB0EQ6AEISDAG#v=onepage&q=antifa%20anarchist&f=false) says:

> This 'loose network' evolved into Antifa, which was predominantly anarchist and took their cue from militant groups in Europe, especially those in Germany who developed the 'black bloc' approach. Antifa emerged around 2004...

Comment: Of course, "antifa" only made it into common use in the past year, and that book was published this year.  There's not really any notable authority as to what the term means.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: The link is to a book on the subject, covering its history. What more could you hope for?

Comment: @DanielRHicks I added quotes from the 2012 book ANTIFA as well.

Comment: So the answer is "Yes"? "Some antifa groups are more Marxist while others are more anarchist or antiauthoritarian." = anti-government, anti-government, and anti-authoritarian. Two out of three ;)

Comment: This answer covers where their roots are from but more straight forward any current violent non government organization is anti-government, the government has a monopoly on violence for good reason, that doesn't change based on what the violent people think about their victims.

Comment: @LangLangC black-and-red color scheme is used equally by communists, anarchicsts and fascists, so I wouldn't read too deep into the flag colors.